# Box Selection supported in Guide4You?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, guide4you

**Is box selection supported in Guide4You?**

If so, how to add that control?

Official Openlayers example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html?q=select

**Thanks in advance!**

Kind regards
Sam

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible through the JS API, but you can do it using OpenLayers in conjunction with guide4you like this:

```
var dragBox = new DragBox();
map.addSupersedingInteraction('singleclick pointermove', dragBox);

// ... use drag Box. And when done call:
dragBox.setActive(false);
// you can reactivate it if you need it again
```

The `addSupersedingInteraction` will cause any other interaction that use `'singleclick'` or `'pointermove'` to be deactivated. As soon as you deactivate dragBox they will get turned on again.

If you are using an older version you need to add `ol.interaction.` before the `DragBox` class.